Plotting a color graph for a dataset
With the following dataset ( https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/yersever/500-person-gender-height-weight-bodymassindex), I am trying to make a graph to show the rate of gender as a function of height and weight.
I’ve tried to get this to work a few different ways and I can’t tell which one is the right one, if any of them are.
# Convert 'Male' to 0 and 'Female' to 1
df[“Gender”] = df[“Gender”].map({“Male”: 0, “Female”: 1})

data_subset = df.copy(True).dropna(subset=“Gender”)

gender_rate = data_subset.groupby([“Height”, “Weight”])[“Gender”].mean().reset_index()

plot = go.Scatter( # I think this one is right but I want to be able to toggle the datasets
        x=gender_rate[“Height”],
        y=gender_rate[“Weight”],
        mode=“markers”,
        marker=dict(
                color=gender_rate[“Gender”],
                colorscale=“Bluered_r”,
                showscale=True,
                colorbar=dict(title=“Gender Rate”),
go.Figure(data=[plot])

I also tried this one in an effort to make the two components togglable
plot=go.Scatter(
         x=data_subset[“Height”],
         y=data_subset[data_subset[“Gender” == 1][“Weight”],
        mode=“markers”,
        name=“Female”,
)

plot1=go.Scatter(
         x=data_subset[“Height”],
         y=data_subset[data_subset[“Gender” == 0][“Weight”],
        mode=“markers”,
        name=“Male”,
)
go.Figure(data=[plot, plot1])


The first approach shows both of the genders together. If you want them to be togglable, use the second approach, however it needs correction. You can use plotly express directly like below.
import plotly.express as px

px.scatter(df, x='Height', y='Weight', color='Gender')

